# Django: Save forms cleaned_data with foreign key as session items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I've got a ModelForm with a number of attributes - in the CreateView `form_valid` method I'm trying to save a users form inputs as session data (which I check for in the `get_initial` method if they visit the form again)

ModelForm:

```
class OrgForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form definition for a Org."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for OrgForm."""

        model = Org
        fields = (
            "full_name",
            "short_name",
            "feature",
            "state",
            "email",
        )
```

View:

```
class OrgCreateView(CreateView):
    "CreateView for OrgForm"
    model = Org
    form_class = OrgForm
    success_url = "/home/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        # Set the form data to session variables
        responses = {}
        for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items():
            responses[k] = v
        self.request.session["org_form_data"] = responses
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(OrgCreateView, self).get_initial()
        # Check for any existing session data
        # This is present if they had filled this out
        # and then came back again later to fill out again
        if "org_form_data" in self.request.session:
            # They have data - loop through and fill it out
            for key, value in self.request.session["org_form_data"]:
                initial[key] = value
        return initial
```

Model:

```
class Org(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Org."""

    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

I have an attribute in there that has a Foreign Key - so when I save the form I get the error:

`Object of type Feature is not JSON serializable`

I'm not sure how best to go about getting around that error - or even if this is the right way to go about it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have solved this issue? facing similar problem.

Comment: Negative. Had to head over to another project not too long after posting this. If I get back to it and figure out an answer, I'll post. Otherwise, it's still open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessions in Django:

### Session Configuration

To set up a session in Django, You need to add two things in your `settings.py`:

```
‘django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware   'to MIDDLEWARE
'django.contrib.sessions   'to INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Run `python manage.py migrate` to populate the table.
The table has three columns:

- session_key
- session_data
- expire_date

### Reading and Writing Session Data

A Django request object has a session attribute that acts like a dictionary.

**Set session data**

```
request.session['user_id'] = ‘20’
request.session['team'] = ‘Barcelona’
```

like *`request.session['your cookie name'] = your value`*

**Read session data**

```
request.session.get('user_id') # returns ‘20’
request.session.get('team') # returns ‘Barcelona’
```

**Delete session data**

```
del request.session['user_id']
del request.session['user_id']
```

I've tried this method, and it works perfectly!
You can ask Django for session values:

```
if request.session('cookiename') == True:
    print("It is TRUE!")
```